# Trigger button press after button hold released

Tags: button, adafruit

I am currently planning a circuit around an Adafruit Sound FX. I want to use it in a costuming prop, but use the main button to trigger different sounds (without them being randomized). It should also light up an LED while the trigger is pressed. I came up with the following circuit:

[image]

**My problem is the following:** in one of the outputs, I added a soundfile that I optimized for looping, as that is something the Adafruit board allows me to do. But since the soundfile is optimized for looping, it's missing an ending. What I want to do is immediately after I let go of the trigger and therefore end the loop, I want to trigger another one of the inputs to play a different sound once. Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

A small explanation of the Adafruit board: to play a sound, the pins 0-10 need to be connected to ground for >125ms. While a sound is playing, the ACT-pin goes low.

I am aware that the LED and power source might be flipped and that there is a resistor missing between the LED and the power source. The image is just here to illustrate the circuit roughly.

Comment: try the `latching loop trigger` ... see if a different trigger will stop the loop

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a SPDT switch then it should be simple:

[image]

When the switch is in the top position the looped sound will play and the LED will light.

When the switch is returned to the bottom position the looped sound will stop and the unlooped sound will trigger. Since it's not looped it will only play once even though the switch is held low.

**EDIT after spec clarification:**

To meet your spec I fear you’ll need to introduce an inverter (a new chip or transistor circuit) to produce a low-going signal when the pushbutton (when connected to input 2) is unpressed.

The inverter output goes low when trigger unpressed and the large capacitor in conjunction with the internal pullup then create a negative pulse of pulse of width about R*C where R is on the order of 10K. 47uF should get you close to the needed 125ms.

The diode is there to shunt the positive spike when the inverter goes high.

[image]

If you want to avoid the inverter you could use separate trigger buttons for 0/1 and for 2/3. For the 2/3 it’s the grounded side of the SPDT that provides the negative signal (instead of an inverter) that the capacitor/resistor convert to a one-time negative pulse.

The 1K resistor quickly discharges the cap while the button is in the 2 position. There is no positive spike to protect against. If you need an LED to light on button 2, probably best to add a second LED.

[image]

Comment: I've thought about using a SPDT switch before, but wouldn't that prevent me from triggering other sounds apart from the loop and one other sound? At least that's why I've chosen not to use one so far.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the parameters of the question - I thought you only had the two sounds. Yes, this circuit won't work for more than the two sounds.  It's not clear (to me) what the conditions of the other sounds are - are they looped/unlooped, how are they intended to interact?

Comment: The main trigger triggers a sound, depending on how the switches are set. In the circuit there are sounds on pins 0, 1 and 2. The sounds on 0 and 1 are unlooped and trigger for each button press. The sound on 2 is looped and will only trigger when the button is held (and the switches are correctly set of course). As soon as the trigger is released, I want another sound to play exactly once at pin 3 (or any other pin). If I then hold down the trigger again, I want the loop in 2 to trigger.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'll accept your answer once I had the chance to try the circuit and everything works.